# What is -33 in binary?

Tags: binary

I was under the impression that it would be 10100001, but I am given a multiple choice question with the following options.  What am I missing here?

11100011

10101011

11011111

11001100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer, I believe, is `1101111` because you're probably using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) representation.

First, write `33` in binary form: `00100001`.

Now invert it (to get one's complement): `11011110`.

Now add one to it (to get two's complement): `11011111`.

Answer (score 0):

It's `11011111`. The classic method was explained by @blazs: write 33 in binary: `00100001`, invert: `11011110` and add one: `11011111`.

To better understand this method, start with figuring out how to represent -1. It is one less than 0, that is one less than `00000000`. The most natural answer is `11111111` (it's probably easier to accept that one more than `11111111` is `00000000`).

So you have:

```
  3    00000011
  2    00000010
  1    00000001
  0    00000000
 -1    11111111
 -2    11111110
 -3    11111101
 -4    11111100
...    ...
-33    11011111
```

When you analyse this for a while, you should be able to reconstruct the two's complement method (invert, add one) by yourself.